# Return updated value in another method

Tags: java

I have two methods where I update the value of a variable in one method, and I want to call the updated value in the second method.

```
// Instance variables
private int numOfFirstClassSeats = 48;
...
```

In my `bookFirstClassSeats` method, I subtract the number of passengers from the number of seats available.

```
numOfFirstClassSeats -= numOfFirstClassAdults;
```

I also have the following getter and setter methods for it.

```
public int getNumOfFirstClassSeats() {
    return numOfFirstClassSeats;
}

public void setNumOfFirstClassSeats(int numOfFirstClassSeats) {
    this.numOfFirstClassSeats = numOfFirstClassSeats;
}
```

So in the first method, I have called the `get` and `set` method.

```
public void bookFirstClassSeats() {
    ...

    // Subtract the number of passengers from the number of seats available.
    numOfFirstClassSeats -= numOfFirstClassAdults;
    System.out.println("Available Seats: " + getNumOfFirstClassSeats());
}
```

The `System.out.println()` prints the correct, updated value, 46.

In my second method, I'd like to display the number of available seats as shown below.

```
public void printAvailableSeats() {
    System.out.println("First Class: " + getNumOfFirstClassSeats();
}
```

**Problem:** When I run this feature I get the same original value, 48. I understand why I'm not getting the updated value, but I haven't figured out yet how to call it.

**EDIT:** To clarify, both of these methods are in the same class. I have another class called `BookingSystem.java`, and I use it to run the `main` method and call the methods above from another class.

Here is my `main` method code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;

    do {
        System.out.println("\n~ BOOKING SYSTEM ~");
        System.out.println("------------------");
        System.out.println("A. Book Seats");
        System.out.println("B. View Available Seats");
        System.out.println("X. Exit\n");

        System.out.print("Select an option: ");
        input = sc.nextLine();

        if (input.length() > 1)
            System.out.println("ERROR: You can only enter a single character!");
        else {
            input = input.toUpperCase();

            switch(input) {
                case "A":
                    new BookingReceipt().bookSeats();
                    break;

                case "B":
                    new BookingReceipt().printAvailableSeats();
                    break;

                case "X":
                    System.out.println("INFO: You have exited the booking system.");
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid input!");
            }
        }
    } while (input.equals("X") == false);

    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: Each time through your menu, you create new BookingRecpt objects, each with their own copies of the instance variables. If you make these variables static, then there will be only one copy and it should work, if they aren't reset in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

well, you made that setter; call it!

For example:

```java
public void bookFirstClassSeats() {
    ...

    // Subtract the number of passengers from the number of seats available.
    numOfFirstClassSeats -= numOfFirstClassAdults;
    setNumOfFirstClassSeats(numOfFirstClassSeats);
    System.out.println("Available Seats: " + getNumOfFirstClassSeats());
}
```

Note the object oriented mindset goes a little further than rote getters and setters. Whatever class has the `numOfFIrstClassSeats` field should probably have the `book` method, too.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are creating a fresh object of the class containing field `private int numOfFirstClassSeats = 48;`. Hence, you're getting the default value. You should use the same object rather creating a new one or you can make that class singleton if this the problem. It would be clear if you can share your main calling method's definition.

As I suspected, you are creating fresh object just create `BookingReceipt` object once.

Create BookingReceipt before do loop starts.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input;
BookingReceipt receipt = new BookingReceipt();
do {
    System.out.println("\n~ BOOKING SYSTEM ~");
    System.out.println("------------------");
    System.out.println("A. Book Seats");
    System.out.println("B. View Available Seats");
    System.out.println("X. Exit\n");

    System.out.print("Select an option: ");
    input = sc.nextLine();

    if (input.length() > 1)
        System.out.println("ERROR: You can only enter a single character!");
    else {
        input = input.toUpperCase();

        switch(input) {
            case "A":
                receipt.bookSeats();
                break;

            case "B":
                receipt.printAvailableSeats();
                break;

            case "X":
                System.out.println("INFO: You have exited the booking system.");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid input!");
        }
    }
} while (input.equals("X") == false);

sc.close();
}
```

Comment: just create your `receipt` object before do loop starts and it should fix the iusse.